# Folium package in Python

Tags: folium

I have created a folium map of US states with some data from a pandas dataframe, and using feature groups to overlay one feature over another.. It works but all of a sudden the legend for the individual features disappear on the choropleth, when I plot it individually (without using feature groups) it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Here is my code snippet...

```
usa_state = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=5)
fg1 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='debt', overlay=False).add_to(usa_state)

folium.Choropleth(
geo_data=state_geo,
data=strumdat,
columns=['state',"debtfree"],
key_on="feature.id",
fill_color='YlGnBu',
fill_opacity=1,
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name="debtfree",
smooth_factor=0,
Highlight= True,
line_color = "#0000",
name = "debtfree",
show=False,
overlay=True,
nan_fill_color = "White"
).geojson.add_to(fg1)

fg2 = folium.FeatureGroup(name='wills', overlay=False).add_to(usa_state)
folium.Choropleth(
geo_data=state_geo,
data=strumdat,
columns=['state',"wills"],
key_on="feature.id",
fill_color='YlGnBu',
fill_opacity=1,
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name="wills",
smooth_factor=0,
Highlight= True,
line_color = "#0000",
name = "Wills",
show=False,
overlay=True,
nan_fill_color = "White"
).geojson.add_to(fg2)


folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(usa_state)
folium_static(usa_state)
usa_state
```

I am not sure why the legend doesnt show up on the overlay but if I plot the features by themselves it works and shows up. I am trying to get as many features into a feature group so we can just toggle between them on the map instead of one map per feature

Comment: Hey, perhaps not really adressing your problem, but if you want to "using feature groups to overlay one feature over another" I think the overlay status should be true, not false:  ```...FeatureGroup(name='...', overlay=True)```

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I will try that. and appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to add `.map` here, as I am not sure it will add the layercontrol without that. See documentation [here](https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/modules.html?highlight=layercontrol#folium.map.LayerControl)

```
# folium.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(usa_state)
folium.map.LayerControl(collapsed=False).add_to(usa_state)
```